# How to edit the selected item of a listview through a usercontrol using WPF, c# and net 7

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, mvvm

at the moment im learning about MVVM and WPF using c#. Im using the Community Toolkit for MVVM 8, Net 7.0 and the WPF UI(Design) package and VS 2022.
Im trying to show a list, with different Items inheriting from the same Interface, on a page. At this same page I want to edit the SelectedItem with a Usercontrol. For this Im currently adding the usercontrol directly to the page, using a Binding to the SelectedItem. Its showing the values in the UserControl but If I change some value the selectedItem of the listview is not updating anymore when I select a different item from the list. Furthermore I want to edit the different models with different usercontrols determined by using a DataTemplate.
Please have a look at following images:

Here is item 1 selected with no edit
[image: Item 1 selected, no edit]
Here is item 2 selected with no edit
[image: Item 2 selected, no edit]
Here is again item 1 selected, but with item 2 edited see first Textbox, but the SelectedItem is not changing anymore
[image: Again Item 1 selected, but item 2 edited]

So here are my 2 Questions:

1. How can I edit the selected Item and change the selected item after editing? Do I have to implement some kind of logic to handle this?
2. How can I use a generic control (like the contentcontrol) to display usercontrols depending on the type using datatemplates? And how to handle the Binding for e.g. the contentcontrol where I have to bind to the content property? Is the contentcontrol even the right choice to use in this case?

ListPage.xaml

```
<ui:UiPage x:Class="EditListItem.Views.Pages.ListPage"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:local="clr-namespace:EditListItem.Views.Pages"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
xmlns:ui="http://schemas.lepo.co/wpfui/2022/xaml"
xmlns:userControls="clr-namespace:EditListItem.Views.UserControls"
Title="ListPage"
d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance local:ListPage, IsDesignTimeCreatable=False}"
d:DesignHeight="450"
d:DesignWidth="800"
d:Background="{DynamicResource ApplicationBackgroundBrush}"
Foreground="{DynamicResource TextFillColorPrimaryBrush}"
mc:Ignorable="d">

<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="9*"></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition Height="1*"></RowDefinition>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid Grid.Row="0">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="6*"></ColumnDefinition>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="4*"></ColumnDefinition>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding ViewModel.Actions, Mode=TwoWay}"
                  SelectionMode="Single"
                  SelectedItem="{Binding ViewModel.SelectedAction, Mode=TwoWay}">
        </ListView>
       
        <userControls:TransactionUserControl Grid.Column="1" Transaction="{Binding ViewModel.SelectedAction, Mode=TwoWay}"/>

    </Grid>
    <WrapPanel Grid.Row="1">
        <Button Content="Deposit" Command="{Binding ViewModel.AddDepositCommand}" />
        <Button Content="Withdrawal" Command="{Binding ViewModel.AddWithdrawalCommand}" />
        <Label Content="{Binding ViewModel.SelectedAction, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
    </WrapPanel>
</Grid>
</ui:UiPage>
```

ListPage.xaml.cs

```
    public partial class ListPage : INavigableView<ViewModels.ListViewModel>
{
        public ViewModels.ListViewModel ViewModel {
            get;
        }

        public ListPage(ViewModels.ListViewModel viewModel)
        {
            ViewModel = viewModel;

            InitializeComponent();
        }
}
```

ListViewModel.cs

```
public partial class ListViewModel : ObservableObject, INavigationAware
{
    private bool _isInitialized = false;

    public ObservableCollection<IAction> Actions { get; set; } = new();

    [ObservableProperty] private IAction? _selectedAction;

    public ListViewModel()
    {
        Actions = new() {
            new Deposit() {
                Id = "1",
                Timestamp = "00000000",
                Amount = 0,
                Symbol = "Symbol1"
            },
            new Withdrawal() {
                Id = "2",
                Timestamp = "00000000",
                Amount = 0,
                Symbol = "Symbol2"
            }
        };
    }

    [RelayCommand]
    private async void AddDeposit()
    {
        Actions.Add(new Deposit());
    }

    [RelayCommand]
    private async void AddWithdrawal()
    {
        Actions.Add(new Withdrawal());
    }

}
```

Here is the control I want to use:

TransactionUserControl.xaml

```
<UserControl x:Class="EditListItem.Views.UserControls.TransactionUserControl"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
             xmlns:userControls="clr-namespace:EditListItem.Views.UserControls"
             d:Background="{DynamicResource ApplicationBackgroundBrush}"
             d:Foreground="{DynamicResource TextFillColorPrimaryBrush}"
             Foreground="{DynamicResource TextFillColorPrimaryBrush}"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="450" d:DesignWidth="400" >
    <StackPanel DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}}">
        <TextBox Text="{Binding Transaction.Id, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
        <TextBox Text="{Binding Transaction.Timestamp, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
        <TextBox Text="{Binding Transaction.Amount, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
        <TextBox Text="{Binding Transaction.Symbol, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
    </StackPanel>
</UserControl>
```

TransactionUserControl.xaml.cs

```
public partial class TransactionUserControl
{

    private static DependencyProperty _transactionProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(nameof(Transaction), typeof(IAction), typeof(TransactionUserControl), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(null, FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.BindsTwoWayByDefault));

    public IAction Transaction {
       get => (IAction)GetValue(_transactionProperty);
       set => SetValue(_transactionProperty, value);
    }

    public TransactionUserControl()
    {
        //DataContext = this;
        InitializeComponent();
    }

}
```

Finally, the Interface Deposit and Withdrawal are inheriting from. The models arent DependencyObjects, pure Models only:

```
public interface IAction
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Timestamp { get; set; }
    public double Amount { get; set; }
    public string Symbol { get; set; }

}

public record Deposit : IAction
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Timestamp { get; set; }
    public double Amount { get; set; }
    public string Symbol { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the `Desposit` class to this in order to update the UI when changing it's properties:

```cs
public class Deposit : ObservableObject, IAction
{
    [ObservableProperty]
    private string _id;

    [ObservableProperty]
    private string _timestamp;

    [ObservableProperty]
    private double _amount;

    [ObservableProperty]
    private string _symbol;
}
```

Comment: I thought you wouldn't do this in model classes? But thanks, that worked. Im kind of dumb not to have thought about this. But by trying this I noticed that its even working if I change the type from record to class without adding the observableobject as a parent.